ZFC replacement schema in FOL
Oliver Deiser, a german author of a famous set theory book I learn with, presents the ZFC replacement schema as follows, link for copy and paste: www.aleph1.info/?call=Puc&permalink=mengenlehre1_3_2_Z12
$\forall p_1,…,p_n (\forall u \exists ! v (\varphi(u,v,p_1,…,p_n)) \implies \forall x \exists y \forall v (v \in y \iff \exists u (u \in x \land \varphi(u,v,p_1,…,p_n))))$.
However, this formulation seems to involve the set $\exists ! v (\varphi(u,v,p_1,…,p_n))$, which, strictly speaking, should not exist in ZFC. Allowing such a set would risk introducing Russell's Paradox, wouldn‘t it? Instead, the variable v should be a subset of an already existing set (separation), which is not mentioned though.
Do you think it is an error or can someone make sense of it?


However, this formulation seems to involve the set $\exists ! v (\varphi(u,v,p_1,…,p_n))$, which, strictly speaking, should not exist in ZFC.

This sentence does not make sense, because $\exists ! v (\varphi(u,v,p_1,…,p_n))$ is not a set. This is simply a logical formula in the first-order language of set theory.
The set $v$ asserted to exist in that formula is part of the hypothesis of the axiom. Only if we already know that such a $v$ exists for every $u$ can we apply the axiom.

Do I understand it correctly? A set like $v$ cannot be generated by ZFC, but it can be assumed in an Antecedens of a ZFC axiom (like it happens in the replacement schema)? Because if $v$ would be contradictory, so what, efq and the axiom still holds and if it is a legit set then it is a legit set.

I think you may be missing a key point: The sub-formula in question is on the left-hand of the implication symbol. So it’s saying that if such a (unique) $v$ exists for every $u$, then the sub-formula to the right of the implication symbol is true.

Also, for a given $\phi$, if such a “collection” of $v$’s (one for each $u$) does exist, that “collection” of $v$’s isn’t necessarily a set — it may well be a proper class.

Thank, NikS, for clarification. So to wrap it up:  {x | P(x)} can be a set in ZFC, right? It is just that you cannot construct it from scratch with ZFC, it can only be a set you assume in an antecedens of an implication, right?

Yes, ${x | P(x) }$ might be a set (depending on what $P(x)$ is), i.e. there might be a set whose members are exactly those $x$’s for which $P(x)$ true. But if there is no such set, then we say that the collection ${x | P(x) }$ is a proper class

I’m not sure what you mean about “constructing from scratch” though. The axioms aren’t like a “recipe” for “constructing” a domain of sets. Rather, they’re like a set of “requirements” that any model of ZFC set theory must satisfy. I can take $\mathfrak{M}$, a model of ZFC, and add more sets to it (e.g. by forcing extension) to yield a new, bigger model $\mathfrak{M}_{2}$ which is also a model of ZFC. This is possible because the axioms don’t limit what sets are allowed to exist (other than requiring that certain rules are obeyed, like the Axiom of Foundation)

One analogy that might be helpful for thinking about this: Consider the field axioms. What are the models of these axioms? There are many. The field of rational numbers, the field of complex numbers, finite fields like $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, and so on.

BTW, to be clear: The implication of Russel’s Paradox is not that ${x | \phi(x) }$ is never a set. Rather, the implication is that we can’t assume it’s always a set; whether it’s a set depends on which formula $\phi$ we’re talking about. As one simple example, if the formula is $\phi : x \neq x$, then ${x | \phi(x) }$ definitely is a set (the empty set, since $x \neq x$ is false for all $x$)

$\forall u \exists ! v (\varphi(u,v,p_1,…,p_n))$ is merely a statement about the formula $\phi$ (given parameters $p_1, \ldots, p_n$). It says that for every $u$ there is a unique $v$ such that $\varphi(u,v,p_1,…,p_n)$ is true. For any given formula $\phi$ it might be a true statement or it might be a false statement, but its truth or falsity for any given $\phi$ does not, in and of itself, have any bearing on Russel’s Paradox.
